# Hashing compromises user security even if to a very low extent.?

Tags: security, hash

In the general practice of hashing a password and storing in database for checking during logon, **there is a slight probability that hacker using my login & different password gets logged in** because of a probability (even though it is infinitesimally small) which seems unacceptable to me (**Two password texts could lead to same hash - use any sha-512,sha-256 alogorithm, iterate hashing 1000 times, use salting... whatever.. HASHING IS NOT  one to one function..**).

How can a user take responsibility for somebody else logging into his account(maybe bank a/c and do some transfers...) with a different password.  **WHY IS THE SYSTEM'S FAULT BEING OVERLOOKED....EVEN IF IT IS A VERY SMALL PROBABILITY?** I very well understand that Hashing is chosen over encryption to prevent the hacker from not getting to the original password if ever the database is broken into...Could some subject expert enlighten me on this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "the system's fault"?

Comment: @PhillipKinkade I mean the whole logic of verifying the password the user enters... hashing it and matching with the hashed password in DB is flawed even if to a very very small extent...

Comment: It's the best we can do, make it easy for our servers to check your password, make any attack infeasably expensive so no-one tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not overlooked, it is a very (very!) small downside one accepts because of the inherent security gains. Because no-one can know wich other password will match the hash, not even the person who knows the password: any attack boils down to guessing.

When guessing passwords for a leaked (correctly implemented) hash, an attacker might need 30 years to compute one possible password or 300 years to guess the exact password - there is no practical difference here, no personal bank account is worth even 30 years of computing.

If the hash is still secure on the server, password guessing is limited by the password strength (your birthday? cats name? etc) instead of the technology used.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Besides, it would be silly to focus on such a small risk and do nothing about phising, SQL injection and CSRF vulnerabilities your web site might have (to name a few).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have skipped over how a salt may help here especially when you consider that the chances of finding a collision are about as likely as you finding the password at random in the first place.

If [my-password + my-salt] ends up being the same hash as yours then it most likely won't when I try [my-password + your-salt] (remember the system forces the correct salt, I only get to enter the password).

Even if I have a list of the systems hashed passwords to spot collisions for my known password. Which would have let me skip a brute force attack. It is not going to be much use since even people with my password are not going to have the same hash as me.

So I'm left to perform a brute force attack to find a collisions which is not a bad place to be given a good system should spot this and block the account.

Comment: I you have access to the hashes, the attack you describe would be done offline. And beleive finding a password at random has a greater probablity than reversing a hash. There are less than 2^128 (output size of MD5) password you can type on a keyboard (especially if you limit yourself to 8 characters).

Comment: That's why security is never one thing if you are using a broken hashing algorithm don't you have bigger problems? If you are using  one designed to make that difficult such as bcrypt with a high enough number of iterations you are attempting to make that harder.

Comment: Using MD5 will be easier to crack, indeed. My point was about finding a password at random. Using a strong hash makes the odds of guessing password even better. +Welcome to StackOverflow! If questions like this one interest you, have a look at security.stackexchange.com.